# SQL Error Code : 1242 / How to convert my code in a table?

Tags: sql

I everybody, despite the reading of many documents and webpages I don't get how to make my code work.

```
select
(select count(*) from toto where (ddate between '2012-01-01' and '2012-12-31') group by produit) "2012",
(select count(*) from toto where (ddate between '2011-01-01' and '2011-12-31') group by produit) '2011',
(select count(*) from toto where (ddate between '2010-01-01' and '2010-12-31') group by produit) '2010'
```

I have a SQL Error Code : 1242 message. And yes it is normal because I do have more than 1 row to return.

How could I handle it ? With the use of PIVOT ? But how ?

Comment: Which database are you using? Whatever the case, please add that tag to the question (eg mysql, sql-server, oracle, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
select produit, 
sum(case when ddate between '2012-01-01' and '2012-12-31' then 1 else 0 end) as '2012',
sum(case when ddate between '2011-01-01' and '2011-12-31' then 1 else 0 end) as '2011',
sum(case when ddate between '2010-01-01' and '2010-12-31' then 1 else 0 end) as '2010'
from toto
where ddate between '2010-01-01' and '2012-12-31'
group by produit
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to *pivot* the data:

```
select produit,
    COUNT(case when ddate = '2012' then produit end) as Year_2012,
    COUNT(case when ddate = '2011' then produit end) as Year_2011,
    COUNT(case when ddate = '2010' then produit end) as Year_2010
from 
(
    select produit,
        year(ddate) ddate
    from toto
    where ddate between '2010-01-01' and '2012-12-31'
) src
group by produit
```

Comment: I'm in two minds as to whether the sub query is a good idea or not. It makes the cases simpler, but the tiny saving (both performance and query size) is lost by doubling the bulk. I expect this would perform about 1/2 as well as well as Kaf's query. I'm going with "not a good idea"

Comment: @Bohemian I just wanted to present an alternate version of the query. My preference would be to use the `PIVOT` function but they did not state the database they are using.